# Не изменяется атрибут value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если добавить [бургер](http://new.monkeyfood.by/products/burgeryi) в корзину, перейти к оформлению заказа (справа вверху) и изменить, скажем, поле "Дом", то в атрибуте value ничего не поменяется. Почему так? Не помогает даже `.change().trigger('change')`

Comment: Фигово. Сочувствую. Попробуйте все-таки поместить имеющиe отношение к вопросу код и маркап в вопрос. А еще лучше создайте пример, воспроизводящий проблему, в редакторе вопроса, используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода".

Comment: Какой код? Кода нет. Есть обычное текстовое поле. Пишу в него 28, а в "Инспекторе элементов" значение value ничему не равно: http://take.ms/bfkek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И не должно. Используйте свойство `value`.

```js
function showValue() {
  var inp = document.querySelector('input');
  console.log(
    inp.outerHTML,
    inp.getAttribute('value'),
    inp.value
  );
}
```

```html
<input value="AAA" /><button onclick="showValue()">Click</button>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819